# Ibeacon using estimote sdk

Tags: android, ibeacon

I am develop ibeacon demo using estimote sdk. Import library to android studio, error like this.
IntelliJ API Decompiler stub source generated from a class file and Implementation of methods is not available. i shared u screenshot. please help as soon as possible.

[image]

Comment: have you tried [this lib](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library) or [this](https://github.com/RadiusNetworks/android-ibeacon-service)??

Answer (score 0):

Estimote's Android SDK source code is not published.

Comment: https://github.com/Estimote/Android-SDK/tree/master/EstimoteSDK. check this link sdk is already published

Comment: SDK is published as compiled code but source code for SDK is not available.